# python BeautifulSoup table scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

my HTML has several tables, the first table is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="string">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the rest are of the form:

```
<table class="confluenceTable" data-csvtable="1">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
             <th class="highlight-grey confluenceTh" data-highlight-colour="grey" rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Negev</th>
```

I want to scrape data from the tables. when I use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'XXX'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read(), "lxml")
for table in soup.findAll('table'):
    print(table)
```

it only finds the first table. when I change the search to:

```
soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "confluenceTable" })
```

it doesn't find anything. What am I missing?

using python 3.4 on windows with BeautifulSoup 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to scrape an *Atlassian Confluence* page which is usually quite dynamic and makes use of JavaScript intensively to load the page. If you look into the HTML source you download with `urllib` you would not find `table` elements with `confluenceTable` class.

Instead, you should either look into using [Confluence API](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api), or use a browser automation tool like [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: It is indeed a confluence page, i'll look into the options you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Congrats on the 200k :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks, of course, closing SO tab now and not answering ever again!